# iOS Face Up Orientation Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, orientation

Is there any way to differentiate between landscape and portrait when the device is sitting on a desk, i.e. UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp? I have two different xib files that I switch between based on the way the user is holding the device. But the problem arrises when I hold the device in landscape, and then place the device down. The device remains in landscape, but will load the portrait xib file. The problem would be opposite if in my coding I coupled the UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp with the landscape orientations: then I would have my landscape view showing when the device is still in portrait.

Is there any way to be able to figure out if the device is still showing landscape or portrait? I have tried checking frame width, but it claims it is 768 even if the device is sitting flat in landscape.  And I can't force an orientation when the device goes flat, I hear thats the road to rejection on the App Store.

Comment: Gravity does not work that way. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The accelerometer can't tell on which side of the phone the user is sitting when it's laid down on a table. You can measure rotation around it's axis using the gyroscope (and the compass), but that still doesn't tell you where the user is unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah. It's kind of a headache for me now though, I specifically need these two views and this really throws a wrench into the whole thing. Everything else works flawlessly, just this one case fails. I find it hard to believe there isn't something built in that's not a headache and half to figure out to help differentiate, I'm sure I'm not the first one to encounter this.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to check it.

`UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation =[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;`
Use the first one to check if the device is in faceup and second one will tell you if the device is in portrait or landscape.